# Smoothing a flat surface in maya

Tags: polygon, maya, smoothing

i was wondering if anyone of u here knows how to smooth a polygon in Maya? I've tried 2 methods which i found online. One of which is 'Vertice Averaging' and the other 'Smooth' which are both under the 'Mesh' option.
Vertice Averaging caused my polygons to have 'gaps' or 'holes' between the triangles, which i do not intend for that to happen.
While Smooth causes the polygon's face to have 4 vertex instead of the original 3, which i do not want as well, as i need a polygon with triangle faces.
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v483/dragonlancer/PolygonAveragingampSmoothing.jpg

And to whoever told me that it is a bug, i tried, but doesnt work =[

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted to maintain your tris so you could switch the smooth option 'Add Divisions' from exponential to linear.

Comment: This is what happens when i change it to linear =[ http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v483/dragonlancer/Untitled2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting gaps, its because the original mesh has verts which are not welded together. Try **Edit Mesh > Merge** with a small tolerance value before running average or smooth.

In general you'll get more pleasant results if you smooth a quadrangular mesh instead of a trimesh - when you subdivide quads the results are very similar to NURBS curves, whereas smoothed triangles always tend to look look like old-fashioned 1990's game graphics.

Comment: oh my! Merging the mesh worked! Thanks! Somehow i don't know why the 3D model captured by the Kinect device doesn't merge the vertices together..<br>
But now i have another problem, doing the merge operation on a small model is fine, but when i apply it to a scene of a room captured by the kinect device, maya kinda hanged.. Cause the model is really huge, consisting of A LOT of triangles.. >_<

Comment: You might want to try running it through a program for editing big point cloud datasets first, such as http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried installing Meshlab but it kept saying i didnt install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistribution Package, but i downloaded and installled, restarted but still can't.. =[

Comment: Sorry it's not working. They do have 32 and 64 bit version, make sure you have the right one.  If you google '3d scan cleanup software' you may be able to find some other free alternative